# ring the phones off the hook

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Is it correct to say

> She's gonna ring the phones off the hook asking for money...

meaning that she will continue calling over and over asking for money. I've heard the phrase "Phones have been ringing off the hook", many times. I just wanted to know if this phrase can be used in this way also.

Comment: Sorry, no.  The image is of multiple calls coming *in* to a phone line (or set of phones lines), not of calls going *out* to other phones.

Comment: What if she calls multiple phones belonging to the same family? Landline and multiple cell phones. Thanks

Comment: It's understandable, but definitely not standard.  *Can* you use it - yes, but it looks strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We normally say **the phone has been ringing off the hook**. It is a reflexive or intransitive verb, but people would understand what you meant if you used the verb transitively.

I suspect this saying may go back to the days of [early phones](https://www.google.com/search?q=antique%20wall%20phone&num=20&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwichZXAhInbAhVwc98KHQATCCUQ_AUICygC&biw=1248&bih=837#imgrc=EqTwupxKwfi-rM:) which had bells that vibrated when ringing. It would mean that the phone's bells have been ringing so much that the earpiece has been shaken off the hook it sits in when the phone is idle.  Over the years the original meaning is forgotten and the phrase becomes a set phrase. Early phone terminology is still used in VoIP.

Answer (score 0):

First, the proposed sentence seems to imply that multiple phones are on one hook. To be correct, you need **hooks**.

Second, the idiom generally refers to multiple calls to one phone, one person, or one office. It does not refer to multiple calls from one person. So it is unlikely that the idiom expresses what you intend.

Comment: But ["off the hook" is such an idiomatic phrase that "off the hooks" sounds weird](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=off+the+hook%2Coff+the+hooks&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coff%20the%20hook%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coff%20the%20hooks%3B%2Cc0), and [Google Ngrams finds many occurrences of *phones* with *hook* but none with *hooks*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=phones+ringing+off+the+*&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cphones%20ringing%20off%20the%20hook%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: If I were going to use a plural, I would use **ring the phones off their hooks**. Probably anything else sounds weird to me because, when I was a young child, receivers on many phones were still hung on literal hooks, and no hook could hold more than one phones. Thus the idiom is still residually a hyperbolic metaphor for me. I doubt anyone under 65 would notice any oddity in pairing multiple phones with one hook because they have no visual memory of the source of the metaphor.